# Point all subdomains to root domain on wordpress website (htaccess)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

I have a WordPress website, lets say, on http://domain.com.

I want to redirect all possible subdomains of the website to main website through htaccess.

Example abcde.domain.com to domain.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the top of the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com/ [L,R]
```